# How to calculate minutes of the day from a UTC milliseconds value w/o time zone offset?

Tags: kotlin, utc, timezone-offset, threetenbp

Given the following time stamp ...

```
2018-09-07T17:00:00+02:00
```

which corresponds to ..

```
UTC: 1536332400000 milliseconds
```

I like to calculate the **amount of minutes** of the day using the [ThreeTen backport library](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp):

```
val dateUtc = 1536332400000L
val offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours(2) // taken from the time stamp
val offsetDateTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(dateUtc).atOffset(offset)
val minutes = offsetDateTime.get(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_DAY)
```

Above works so far.
Is there a way to **avoid** defining the **zone offset** since the UTC milliseconds already implicitly the zone offset of `0`?

## Related

- https://www.epochconverter.com - for getting the milliseconds value